# Update docker version where containers are running

Tags: docker

Can't seem to find recommended way to do this.
I have a vm host using unintuitive running a number of containers.
It is using an older version of docker and I want to update.
What are the steps to do this?
Stop containers.
Do update of docker version
Restart containers.

Trying to minimise downtime and don't have the option to bring up a new vm. Also vm contains volume data I don't want to lose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your distribution, run command to update docker.
e.g. on CentOS run `yum update docker-engine`

This will stop your containers, update docker and start containers which were configured to restart automatically (e.g. `docker run --restart=always ...`).

Please note that in case your container is configured to be removed automatically (`docker run --rm ...`) you will loose all data associated with the container unless you manage the data via volumes.

In case you use external service discovery tool, the port mapping of the exposed ports usually change so you should trigger an update of the ports in the external service discovery tool.